# My WPF app is not starting but there are no errors in the errors tab?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, registry

This is the code of my user control

```
 public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"CurrentControlSet\Services\XblGameSave");
        uint value = (uint)key.GetValue("Start");
        if (value == 4)
        {
            Disable_Xbox_Services.IsChecked = true;
        }
    }
```

But when I run my app, then it does not start even there are no errors in the errors tab. Pls tell me the reason for that. This is the XAML code for the checkbox.

```
 <CheckBox Name="Disable_Xbox_Services" FontSize="26" Foreground="GhostWhite" >Disable Xbox services</CheckBox>
```

Comment: Start -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application: find out if there are some exceptions related to your application

Comment: The error tab does not show runtime errors, if this makes sense. You must run the application in debug mode to learn about runtime errors of your application. Logging can also help. But running in debug mode is more convenient in your case as the debugger will break at the exact line where the error occurred.

Comment: If something doesn't behave as expected you must post all the related code that reproduces the issue. Reviewing code snippets is useless. [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: The code which I have attached for user control produces the issue. If I remove the code after InitializeComponent() there, then the app again works normally. Pls look into that and guide me if I can use that code some other way so it doesn't produce the issue.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the line after InitializeComponent, then step through your code to see where an exception occurs. Take a look at the details of the exception to find out what happend.

Comment: Probably this is because you're not running your app as admin, so you don't have the permission to read from registry.. so if you run your app as admin from debug folder, it may work without any issue. Anyway, Are not you running your code in Visual Studio in Debug mode? Does not it stop at the line where the exception occur? Wrap your code in try/catch block and put a breakpoint at catch statement to read the exception message.

Comment: Debugging would make you realize that `key` is null, because that key does not exist. Maybe you wanted to open `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblGameSave`.

Comment: You don't need admin to read from registry.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the correct registry subkey name, and `int` as value type:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
    @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\XblGameSave");

int value = (int)key.GetValue("Start"));
if (value == 4)
{
    Disable_Xbox_Services.IsChecked = true;
}
```